# How would I keep track of the amount of discs in a connect 4 board and JUnit test methods in java?

Tags: java, eclipse, multidimensional-array, junit

I've been working on a connect 4 program in java and and I have been doing some checks of the validity of board but I have encountered a few problems when developing my code. For reference here's the code with comments

```
public class Connect4 {
     public static void main(String args[]) {
            char[][] board = new char[][]{///2d array for board
                    {'.', '.', '.', 'Y', 'R', '.','.'},
                    {'.', '.', '.', 'Y', 'R', '.','.'},
                    {'.', '.', '.', 'Y', 'R', 'Y','.'},
                    {'.', '.', '.', 'Y', 'R', 'R','.'},
                    {'.', '.', '.', 'Y', 'R', 'Y','.'},
                    {'.', '.', '.', 'Y', 'R', 'R','.'},             
                };
            System.out.println("\n1.2/ Is this Board Valid?");
            System.out.println(Q2_ValidBoard(board) + " this (is/is not) a valid board.");
            System.out.println();
     }

            public static boolean Q2_ValidBoard(char[][] board) {
                int allowedRows = 6;///allowed row size for board
                int allowedColumns = 7;///allowed size for columns
                if ((board == null) || (board.length == 0)) { //checks if array is empty
                    System.out.println("Array is Empty");
                    return false;
                }

                // Verify Board Size and Each Square of the Board
                // Condition 1 - Check if The Size Of Rows is 6 / If Height is 6
                if(board.length != allowedRows) {System.out.println("Number of Rows is Not " + allowedRows); return false;}

                for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) { // For Each Row in Board..
                    if (board[i].length != allowedColumns) { // Check if Size of Column is 6 / If Width is 7
                        System.out.println("Number of Column's is Not " + allowedColumns + " on ROW " + (i + 1));///Declares if the 
                        return false;
                    }

                    // Condition 2 - Check whether Each Square has a Valid Value
                    for (int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) { // For Each Column in Board..
                        if(((board[i ][j] != 'R')&&(board[i][j] != 'Y')&&(board[i][j] != '.'))) {
                            System.out.println("Invalid Board Square At " + (i + 1) + " x " + (j + 1));
                            return false; // If The Square isn't R, Y or . it's not Valid
                        }
                    }

                }

                // Condition 3 - Loop Backwards and Check if a Disc is Floating
                for (int i = board.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    for (int j = (board[i].length - 1); j >= 0; j--) {
                        if ((board[i][j] == 'R') || (board[i][j] == 'Y')) {
                            if (i != allowedRows - 1) { // Make sure to check it's not the deepest row level or it will call an error as it looks OutOfBounds of the List (-1)
                                if(board[i + 1][j] == '.') { // You want to increment to go deeper in the 2D array not decrease; you're already going backwards.
                                    System.out.println("Disc is Floating at " + (i + 1) + " x " + (j + 1));
                                    return false;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                ///Condition 4 check if the amount of discs is fair
                int redCount = 0;
                int yellowCount = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < board.length;i++) {
                    for (int j = 0 ;j < board[i].length; j++) {
                        if (board[i][j] == 'R'){
                            System.out.println("red disc found");
                            redCount++;
                        }else if (board[i][j] == 'Y') {
                        System.out.println("yellow disc found");
                        yellowCount++;
                    }
                 }

                if (redCount - yellowCount > 1){///If the difference between red and yellow discs is greater than one then the board is invalid
                    System.out.println("Amount of discs isn't fair. There are too many red discs and thus the board is invalid. There are " + redCount + " reds and " + yellowCount + " yellows.");
                    System.out.println(redCount);
                    return false;

                }
                else if (yellowCount > redCount) {///If there are more yellows than reds then the board is invalid since red is always meant to go first
                    System.out.println("Amount of discs isn't fair. There are too many yellow discs and thus the board is invalid. There are " + redCount + " reds and " + yellowCount + " yellows.");
                    return false;
                }


                    }
                System.out.println("The number of red discs is " + redCount + ". And the number of yellow discs is " + yellowCount );
                return true;
   
    
            }
}
```

The board I inputted should be valid since the amount of reds and yellows are equivalent. The conditions for the correct proportion of discs are listed within the code comments.

When I input the board I am told that the board is invalid and false is returned

```
1.2/ Is this Board Valid?
yellow disc found
red disc found
yellow disc found
red disc found
yellow disc found
red disc found
yellow disc found
Amount of discs isn't fair. There are too many yellow discs and thus the board is invalid. There are 3 reds and 4 yellows.
false this (is/is not) a valid board.
```

As you can see the board has more than 3 yellows and 4 reds (8 red discs and 8 yellow discs) but there is something in the code which is stopping the counting of discs within the nested loop which counts the number of reds and yellows.

```
///Condition 4 check if the amount of discs is fair
                int redCount = 0;
                int yellowCount = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < board.length;i++) {
                    for (int j = 0 ;j < board[i].length; j++) {
                        if (board[i][j] == 'R'){
                            System.out.println("red disc found");
                            redCount++;
                        }else if (board[i][j] == 'Y') {
                        System.out.println("yellow disc found");
                        yellowCount++;
                    }
                 }

                if (redCount - yellowCount > 1){///If the difference between red and yellow discs is greater than one then the board is invalid
                    System.out.println("Amount of discs isn\'t fair. There are too many red discs and thus the board is invalid. There are " + redCount + " reds and " + yellowCount + " yellows.");
                    System.out.println(redCount);
                    return false;

                }
                else if (yellowCount > redCount) {///If there are more yellows than reds then the board is invalid since red is always meant to go first
                    System.out.println("Amount of discs isn't fair. There are too many yellow discs and thus the board is invalid. There are " + redCount + " reds and " + yellowCount + " yellows.");
                    return false;
                }
```

How would I fix this problem and how can I use JUnitTesting to test my code? I've been unable to work out how to use JUnitesting so should help.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The code with Condition 4 and printing would suffice in the valid board method.

Additionally remember to keep your question focused, it should only ask one thing at a time. The JUnit should be a separate question with an attempt at using it and problem encountered.

Answer (score 0):

### Running JUnit tests & debug in Eclipse

If you want to **include JUnit in your project** I recommend this tutorial as it will guide you step by step through how to run JUnit tests for your Java application: [Running JUnit Tests from a Java Application](https://baeldung-cn.com/junit-tests-run-programmatically-from-java)

To find why the program does not work as expected you should try to run the Java program in **Debugging mode** (as you've included the `eclipse` tag I assume you are using Eclipse as your main IDE, so this tutorial might help: [Beginner’s Guide to Quick Start Debugging](https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2017/june/article1.php))

### **Debugging process**

- I've placed a breakpoint on **line 60** (`for (int i = 0; i < board.length;i++) {` ) and then went through some iteratiosn of your loop.
- The error is occuring due to the fact that you are not closing the curly brackets correctly (as you are running the following block

```java
if (redCount - yellowCount > 1){///If the difference between red and yellow discs is greater than one then the board is invalid
                   System.out.println("Amount of discs isn't fair. There are too many red discs and thus the board is invalid. There are " + redCount + " reds and " + yellowCount + " yellows.");
                   System.out.println(redCount);
                   return false;

               }
               else if (yellowCount > redCount) {///If there are more yellows than reds then the board is invalid since red is always meant to go first
                   System.out.println("Amount of discs isn't fair. There are too many yellow discs and thus the board is invalid. There are " + redCount + " reds and " + yellowCount + " yellows.");
                   return false;
               }


                   }
               System.out.println("The number of red discs is " + redCount + ". And the number of yellow discs is " + yellowCount );
               return true;
```

inside the `for-loop of variable i`.)

- **How to fix**: you should close the for-loop of 'i' 's curly bracket before starting to run the code block that I pasted above. After closing the curly brackets correctly, there should be an additional closing curly bracket on **line 83** that you will have to delete.

### Code snippet after editing

```java
public class Connect4 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        char[][] board = new char[][]{///2d array for board
                {'.', '.', '.', 'Y', 'R', '.', '.'},
                {'.', '.', '.', 'Y', 'R', '.', '.'},
                {'.', '.', '.', 'Y', 'R', 'Y', '.'},
                {'.', '.', '.', 'Y', 'R', 'R', '.'},
                {'.', '.', '.', 'Y', 'R', 'Y', '.'},
                {'.', '.', '.', 'Y', 'R', 'R', '.'},
        };
        System.out.println("\n1.2/ Is this Board Valid?");
        System.out.println(Q2_ValidBoard(board) + " this (is/is not) a valid board.");
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static boolean Q2_ValidBoard(char[][] board) {
        int allowedRows = 6;///allowed row size for board
        int allowedColumns = 7;///allowed size for columns
        if ((board == null) || (board.length == 0)) { //checks if array is empty
            System.out.println("Array is Empty");
            return false;
        }

        // Verify Board Size and Each Square of the Board
        // Condition 1 - Check if The Size Of Rows is 6 / If Height is 6
        if (board.length != allowedRows) {
            System.out.println("Number of Rows is Not " + allowedRows);
            return false;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) { // For Each Row in Board..
            if (board[i].length != allowedColumns) { // Check if Size of Column is 6 / If Width is 7
                System.out.println("Number of Column's is Not " + allowedColumns + " on ROW " + (i + 1));///Declares if the
                return false;
            }

            // Condition 2 - Check whether Each Square has a Valid Value
            for (int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) { // For Each Column in Board..
                if (((board[i][j] != 'R') && (board[i][j] != 'Y') && (board[i][j] != '.'))) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid Board Square At " + (i + 1) + " x " + (j + 1));
                    return false; // If The Square isn't R, Y or . it's not Valid
                }
            }

        }

        // Condition 3 - Loop Backwards and Check if a Disc is Floating
        for (int i = board.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            for (int j = (board[i].length - 1); j >= 0; j--) {
                if ((board[i][j] == 'R') || (board[i][j] == 'Y')) {
                    if (i != allowedRows - 1) { // Make sure to check it's not the deepest row level or it will call an error as it looks OutOfBounds of the List (-1)
                        if (board[i + 1][j] == '.') { // You want to increment to go deeper in the 2D array not decrease; you're already going backwards.
                            System.out.println("Disc is Floating at " + (i + 1) + " x " + (j + 1));
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        ///Condition 4 check if the amount of discs is fair
        int redCount = 0;
        int yellowCount = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
                if (board[i][j] == 'R') {
                    System.out.println("red disc found");
                    redCount++;
                } else if (board[i][j] == 'Y') {
                    System.out.println("yellow disc found");
                    yellowCount++;
                }
            }

        }
            if (redCount - yellowCount > 1){///If the difference between red and yellow discs is greater than one then the board is invalid
                System.out.println("Amount of discs isn't fair. There are too many red discs and thus the board is invalid. There are " + redCount + " reds and " + yellowCount + " yellows.");
                System.out.println(redCount);
                return false;

            }
            else if (yellowCount > redCount) {///If there are more yellows than reds then the board is invalid since red is always meant to go first
                System.out.println("Amount of discs isn't fair. There are too many yellow discs and thus the board is invalid. There are " + redCount + " reds and " + yellowCount + " yellows.");
                return false;
            }


        System.out.println("The number of red discs is " + redCount + ". And the number of yellow discs is " + yellowCount );
        return true;


    }
}
```

- After closing the brackets correctly and running the code below, you should see the following output:

```
1.2/ Is this Board Valid?
yellow disc found
red disc found
yellow disc found
red disc found
yellow disc found
red disc found
yellow disc found
yellow disc found
red disc found
red disc found
yellow disc found
red disc found
yellow disc found
yellow disc found
red disc found
red disc found
The number of red discs is 8. And the number of yellow discs is 8
true this (is/is not) a valid board.
```

I hope this helps fixing your bug!

Comment: Hey you wrote square brackets [ but it looks like you meant curly brackets {

Comment: @CausingUnderflowsEverywhere Thanks for observing the typo, I'll edit my answer